# compare string from 2 different collections and extract the difference

Tags: c#

I need to compare 2 sets of string which have some similar names and I need to extract the similar names, how can I do that? They are both collections and lets say one of them is "Sanjay, Race" and the other is "Let, Sanjay", I need to extract Sanjay.

Comment: need to see the actual data you have.  How can one collection be "SAnjay, Race", thats a string not a collection

Comment: @pm100 They are probably listing the values comma separated, but putting the entire "collection" in quotes does confuse things.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what data structure you have but I suggest you work with an Array or a List if you collection is big enough to care about optimisation.

You want to go through the first of the two lists, and for each element of list1, compare to compare to every element of list2. Be careful, this might take a while (if your collection is big enough).

Might look like :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
LinkedList<string> set1 = new LinkedList<string>();
LinkedList<string> set2 = new LinkedList<string>();
LinkedList<string> extracted = new LinkedList<string>();
//fill in your sets with loops if needed :
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-7.0

```
   foreach (string name in set1){
       foreach (string name2 in set2){
          if(string.Compare(name,name2)==0){
             extracted.AddAfter(name);
          }
       }
   }
```

Please, do correct me (nicely) :)